# One to one relationship with FK in one direction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-one

How do I get the following relationship to only generate the FK in Entity2?

```
  public class Entity1
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public virtual Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
  }

  public class Entity2
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public int? Entity1Id { get; set; }

     public virtual Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
  }
```

I want Entity1 be able to get a reference to an Entity2 (have EF lazy load it), but I don't want Entity1 to have an FK to Entity2 in the db, I just want Entity2 to have an FK to Entity1.  Is this possible?  Everything I have been trying in OnModelCreating in my db context isn't getting me what I really want.

The closest I can get is this:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Entity2>().HasOptional(e => e.Entity1).WithOptionalDependent(e => e.Entity2);
```

However, this will create the Entity2 table with an Entity1Id column AND an Entity1_Id FK column to Entity1, instead of just creating the single Entity1Id column that should be an FK to Entity1.

Also, in case anyone asks, the Entity1Id property is intentionally a nullable int because a Entity2 instance/table record needs to exist independently without a link to Entity1.

Comment: Why is it you can achieve this if it were a one to many relationship, but not one to one?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code in OnModelCreating, and add this annotation to your Entity2

```
public class Entity2
{
 public int Id { get; set; }

 [ForeignKey("Entity1")]
 public int? Entity1Id { get; set; }

 public virtual Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
```

}

Or you can try this (I don't know if it work or not)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity2>()
.HasOptional(e => e.Entity1)
.WithOptionalDependent(e => e.Entity2)
.Map(m => { m.MapKey("Entity1Id"); });
```

Comment: Thanks! So I was really trying to avoid the dataannotations approach - is this the only way then?

Comment: It didn't like either solution - the first one (the data annotation route) it says that multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Entity2_Entity1_Source' in relationship 'Entity2_Entity1'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.  For the other solution, it complains that each property name must be unique and indicates that Entity1Id is already defined on there, so it seems it's trying to create that column twice.

Comment: Side note, modelBuilder.Entity<Entity2>().HasOptional(e => e.Entity1).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.Entity1Id); seems to produce the same results in the constructed tables as modelBuilder.Entity<Entity2>().HasOptional(e => e.Entity1).WithOptionalDependent(e => e.Entity2); ...so I'm wondering what the real difference between these is if they produce the same thing.