# EF Codefirst, difference between .WithMany().HasForeignKey() and .WithOptionalDependent()

Tags: entity-framework

Both

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity2>().HasOptional(e => e.Entity1).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.Entity1Id);
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity2>().HasOptional(e => e.Entity1).WithOptionalDependent(e => e.Entity2);
```

Seem to produce the same results when building the two database tables - so what is the real difference between them and which is the correct usage?

Models:

```
 public class Entity1
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
 }

 public class Entity2
 {   
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? Entity1Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
 }
```

Produces these tables:

```
Entity1
------------
PK Id
FK Entity2_Id  (which I do not want it to create this FK anyway)

Entity2
------------
PK Id
FK Entity1d
```

Comment: This is related to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027895/one-to-one-relationship-with-fk-in-one-direction ...but different in that I would like to just understand the difference between these two particular model builder approaches since they seem to do the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your model, the second option is correct.

Even though both options result in the same database schema, the first option would be used if Entity1 contained a collection of Entity2 objects (which is what the WithMany() is specifying).

Something like...

```
public class Entity1
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Entity2> Entity2Instances { get; set; }
}
```

...instead of...

```
public class Entity1
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public virtual Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so does this have an impact on how the queries are constructed then too?  For example, if I were to keep using the WithMany approach, would a query for the Entity2 that belongs to Entity1 be actually created in such a way that it was optimized to look for multiple child objects, not just one?